# EclipseLink internal logging statements go through Log4j2

Tags: eclipselink, log4j2

I want the internal logging statements from EclipseLink (version 2.7.x) to be logged through my Log4j2 setup.

I know there's a bug report on this (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-444) which never got solved. I also know, there is a wiki how to implement an own logger (https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/Foundation/Logging).

Since I think someone must have already addressed this problem (since there should be thousands of EclipseLink + log4j2 setups out there) and come out with a reliable solution, my question would be:
Where can i find it?

Comment: What is unreliable about using the CommonsLoggingSessionLog.java class specified in the logging wiki you linked?

Comment: Adding commons-logging and the log4j2-commons-logging-bridge to the classpath seems a total overkill to me.

Comment: What is the solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this solution is the best, but

1. The library contain EclipseLink logger impelementation for slf4j:
   https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.extension
2. You can set it to use in `persistence.xml`:
   `<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="org.eclipse.persistence.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger" />`
3. Now you need bridge slf4j -> log4j2:
   https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl
4. And finally `log4j2.xml`: `<Logger name="eclipselink.logging" level="ALL"> ... </Logger>`
5. `level="ALL"` because what exatly will be logged is configured in `persistence.xml` e.g. `eclipselink.logging.level` property an so on:
   https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging